# Domain "jerryhanks.me" is still being processed by CustomerID - Bluehost

Tags: dns, hosting, web-hosting

I am trying to assign my domain wwww.jerryhank.me to my cpanel in Bluehost and this is what i get when ever i try to do that.

```
Domain "jerryhanks.me" is still being processed by CustomerID
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that's something only BlueHost support can tell you.

Comment: But they have not been able to do that, what if some one here can help me.

Comment: As your question is not programming related, it's offtopic on SO. And it's astonishing that they cannot help you with a problem with their product.

Comment: just to check: it's not the difference between jerryhank and jerryhankS, is it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to contact Bluehost support as they have the root access and other stuff to fix the issue.